# Does Ubuntu Core support LVM?

Tags: lvm, ubuntu-core

My initial try at Ubuntu Core got me surprised by the lack of LVM (Logical Volume Manager) commands. The Snap store doesn't seem to have anything either.

Comment: What do the terminal commands `man -k lvm;apt-cache search lvm` tell you. Don't tell us, read it yourself.